# Laptop shuts off after disconnected from power. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, hibernate

As the question says, whenever the laptop is disconnected/removed from the charger, it goes into hibernate mode and cannot be "woke up" until it's connected to the charger again. I've tried changing through ever power setting, going into the advanced battery settings, and have also tried getting a new battery. How can I fix this?

Asus X55A running Windows 8

Comment: Does this happen if you boot instead from an Ubuntu LiveUSB? Instructions to make: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  - Trying to pin this down as to hardware vs software.

Comment: Tried to use it but it still happens. I think it's software but I'm not sure what's causing it to go into sleep/hibernate.

Comment: Is your BIOS up-to-date?

Comment: Also, is Power4Gear Hybrid app installed on the laptop? The manual says "Unplugging the Notebook PC from its power adapter
automatically switches Power4Gear Hybrid to Battery Saving Mode" so you might like to have a look on its settings if it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Since it happens with an Ubuntu LiveUSB, it's a hardware fault. Since you replaced the battery, it's in the laptop itself unless the factory-shipped battery and the aftermarket battery were from the same batch.